# How to be recursive with Datatable rerender function

Tags: datatables

I am getting my Json from my server after i do a query, I could look through this array, but for purpose of this I am not doing it.

As you will see on my code below I need to check if some of the fields are not null to avoid the JS error message that pop ups when the table is going to be render.

my question is, i it possible to create a function that will be call instead of rewritting the function on the columns that I need?

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
    oTable = jQuery("#campaignMembers").dataTable({
    "aaData": {!campaignMembers},
    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "bFilter": true,
    "tableTools": {"sSwfPath": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"},
    "aoColumns": [
                    {"mData": "Client__r.FirstName"},
                    {"mData": "Client__r.PersonMobilePhone","render":  test()},
                    {"mData": "Client__r.BillingState","render":  function (data,type,row,meta){
                    if(data == null){return '';}else{return data;}
                    }},
                    {"mData": "Client__r.Client_Manager_Name__c","render":  function (data,type,row,meta){
                    if(data == null){return '';}else{return data;}
                    }},
    ]
    }); 
});
```

I was trying something like

```
    function test(data,type,row,meta){
    if(data == null){
            return '';
    }else{
            return data;
    }
}
```

and then on the column definition

```
    {"mData": "Client__r.BillingState","render":  test (data,type,row,meta)},
```

Comment: share your error info when you trying so . try making function `(function(){//check valid cond})();` self excecuted onload of js file

Comment: Hi, I am sorry but your comment it is not very clear, just in case there is no problem with the function, what i need is some how to be able to call from the datatable definition, instead of writting the function again and again. This way the code will be cleaner and easier to mantain. thanks